# Why does protobuf::message::GetMessage return a reference?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

When looking at the protobuf interface for Message Reflection, there seem to be two functions: `GetMessage` and `MutableMessage`. Naively one could think, that the former is just the const variant of the latter. It seems however, since the former is returning a reference instead of a pointer, that these 2 do different things. Sadly I could not yet find any in-depth documentation as to what the conceptual difference between the two are.

Does anyone know and can elaborate?

Comment: I'd guess that `MutableMessage` can return `nullptr`?

Comment: One of the questions is, why `MutableMessage` can, but `GetMessage` can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former really is just the `const` version of the latter, except for the case where the field is not set (yet): In this case, `GetMessage` returns a default value and `MutableMessage` a newly allocated instance.

The fact that a `const` reference is returned highlights that this method never returns `nullptr`. And it's also consistent with the generated API this way.

Comment: Ah, thanks this makes sense. Makes me fear the performance impact of `MutableMessage` now.

Comment: The instance allocation is only performed once, after this the field will be set and has() will return true. That said, you'll want to avoid this if you don't need it obviously. And otherwise you can't avoid the allocation anyway...

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I seriously could not find too much documentation :(

Answer (score 2):

The reason one uses a reference and the other a pointer is that the [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html) specifies that [references must always be const](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments), and that pointers should be used for mutable objects (even when the pointer is not allowed to be null). This is purely a matter of style. One way to think of it is that passing by const reference is like an optimized version of passing by copy: the syntax looks the same and the semantics are very similar but you avoid the actual copy step.

(That said, speaking as the author of the code you're talking about, I am personally not a fan of this rule.)

Stefan Haustein is correct that `GetMessage()` can return a default value while `MutableMessage()` ensures that the message is initialized, but this is unrelated to the reference/pointer difference.